# Controlar primer inicio de sesión ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto con C# asp.net, y necesito saber como puedo controlar el primer inicio de sesión de un usuario, es decir, cuando el usuario inicia sesión por primera vez el sistema le debe enviar un correo electrónico al usuario con un link que le permitirá crear su clave para ingresar, sin embargo no sé como hacer esa validación al login del sistema ya que todo el control de usuario lo manejan con UserManager Identity de ASP.NET

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es consultar tu base de datos, a veri si existe algún registro en tu campo de password, dependiendo de eso ya podrás mandar un correo electrónico. 
Aunque lo mas lógico es que cuando inicies sesión, ya deberías tener un password.
Puedes agregar la lógica de crear la clave del usuario, cuando se este registrando.

Comment: Puedes crear  un proceso de Registro digamos que el usuario te da su correo por primera ves y Nombre de usuario,  asi tendras una tabla que llames digamos PreRegistro (RegistroId, Usuario, correo, claveRegistro) ,despues de iniciar ese proceso de registro envias el email al Usuario el link lleva el nombre del sitio/registro/clave. Una vez que validas la clave lo rediriges a una actualizacion de pasword